# В списке из словарей как добавлять новый ключи со значением суммы предыдущих значений Python

Tags: python

подскажите у меня список из множества словарей, нужно добавить еще один элемент состоящего из ключа и значения, который б суммировал б значение предыдущего: проще говоря

`my_list = [{'amount':1}, {'amount':2}, {'amount':3}]`  и этот список нужно преобразовать в  `my_list = [{'amount':1, 'total_amount':1}, {'amount':2, 'total_amount':3}, {'amount':3, 'total_amount':6}]`
то есть прибавляет значение предыдущего элемента amount..сначала 1 потом 3(1+2) потом 6(3+3)

Answer (score 3):

```py
my_list = [{'amount':1}, {'amount':2}, {'amount':3}]

total_amount = 0
for el in my_list:
    total_amount += el['amount']
    el['total_amount'] = total_amount

print(my_list)
```

Результат:

> [{'amount': 1, 'total_amount': 1}, {'amount': 2, 'total_amount': 3}, {'amount': 3, 'total_amount': 6}]

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [{'amount':1}, {'amount':2}, {'amount':3}]
new_list = []
total_amount = 0
for element in my_list:
    total_amount += element['amount']
    new_element = {'amount': element['amount'], 'total_amount': total_amount}
    new_list.append(new_element)
print(my_list) # [{'amount':1}, {'amount':2}, {'amount':3}]
print(new_list) # [{'amount': 1, 'total_amount': 1}, {'amount': 2, 'total_amount': 3}, {'amount': 3, 'total_amount': 6}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import itemgetter, add

my_list = [{'amount':1}, {'amount':2}, {'amount':3}]
totals = accumulate(map(itemgetter('amount'), my_list), add)
result = [dict(rec, total_amount=total) for rec, total in zip(my_list, totals)]
print(result)
```